# Tabs, Text-Mate, Editing HTML (Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textmate, tabs

Is there any way to force Text-Mate to use a two-space tab instead of a full tab when editing HTML (Rails) documents?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. There's a pop-up menu near the bottom middle of the window that probably reads `Tabs: 4` or something like that. Click on it and hange it to `2` and `Soft Tabs`.

You should have an `rhtml` or `erb` document (or whatever file type you want to change) open for editing when doing this. The changes will stick for all documents of that type.

Answer (score 3):

On the topic of tabs, these TextMate menu commands are also helpful:

- Text -> Convert -> Spaces to Tabs
- Text -> Convert -> Tabs to Spaces

Tabs to Spaces is very helpful for fixing tab-related errors when working in with [Haml](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/) documents.